# How to check whether multiple columns have the same values in a database

Tags: python, database, ms-access, multiple-columns, rows

I am trying to use python to check database columns for the same values.

example:

|3| = number in a row

|4| |3| = 1 row 2 columns

```
|3| |4| |5|
|6| |2| |9|
|3| |4| |5|
```

so I would want the python code to run through this database and Read the first one and store it in a variable and then do the same for every new one it finds but if it finds a repeat of one it would then calculate the highest repeat and out put them in order from greatest to least number of repeats.

example:

```
|3| |4| |5|
|6| |2| |9|
|3| |4| |5|
|3| |4| |5|
|6| |2| |9|
|7| |1| |3|

output: 3,4,5
        6,2,9
        7,1,3
```

Comment: Concatenate per row, run a count over your concatenated values and order descending over the count. You don't need Python for this.

Comment: Could you demonstrate please?

Comment: In the output, what about `3, 5, 5`?  Also, if you're going to give sample database data, please give column names also so other don't have to guess or make up names when trying to give a solution.

Comment: @Rene  Do you mean aggregate?  Concatenate means to join in a series.

Comment: I agree with Rene that you don't need Python.  But even if you need to do it with Python, Stack Overflow is not meant to be a code writing service.  It is expected that you show us what you have tried and where the problem is, not just a request for complete code.  This also looks suspiciously like a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

Within Python, open a new RecordSet from Access using the following query.  Group by all values for which you want to get distinct values and then sort on the COUNT() aggregate function:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Column1, Column2, Column3
ORDER BY Count(Column1) Desc
```